# Issue calling a function for a user selected folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that prompts the user to select a folder and a subroutine that will consolidate the files in the folder to a single document, but I cannot get the two to work together.

```
Function GetFolder() As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Sub ConslidateWorkbooksPrompt()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderPath = GetFolder()
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I save the subroutine separately and run it where FolderPath = "C:\docs\SampleFolder\" then it runs fine. Instead of having to manually change the folder path, I'd like the user to be able to select their own, but I imagine I am somehow calling the function wrong.

Comment: try adding `Debig.Print FolderPath` after `FolderPath = GetFolder()` to check the string value in the immediate window. You may need to add the `/` to the string...

Comment: @Mistella Did you mean `Debug.Print`? And changing `FolderPath = GetFolder()` to `FolderPath = GetFolder() & "\"` worked

Comment: Yes, `Debug.Print`.  :)  Glad you got it working.

Comment: @gr33ns Something to look out! If you click Cancel from file dialog, you will have an issue when `GetFolder()` returns empty string `""`.